# Bluetooth LE dual-mode

Tags: bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible for the Bluetooth dual-mode device to be discoverable by classic bluetooth at the same time as being pairable with BT LE devices?
It's ok if the device can not operate with both at the same time, but should I switch the chip between those modes really?
I just can not find the answer in the BT 4 Core Specification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, A dual mode device can be discoverable by classic Bluetooth while being connected to a LE device.
The device can also be connected to both classic and LE at the same time (device will time multiplex so as to maintain operations on both Classic and LE simultaneously)

Comment: Your answer does help. By any chance do you know any open source project which demonstrates that further for a good understanding of the implementation technique?

Comment: how to know if bt chip in android phone supports dual mode? is it written somewhere in specs? is there a list of devices somewhere? Can that be checked in runtime? 10q