# Disconnecting and closing BLE connection stops classic Blutetooth PBAP profile

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I have a setup with two Android devices: an android phone and a custom hardware running Android 10. The latter acts as a BLE Server, which is discoverable always with the same static MAC address. Also when that custom HW is paired with the phone it has access to phone's contacts and calls history. That HW can also play media (sound) streamed from the phone.

I use RxAndroidBle 1.11.0 library for BLE communication. As soon as I exchange some data via BLE Characteristic I unsubscribe from the RX observable so the library effectively calls: `bluetoothGatt.disconnect()` then `blutetoohGatt.close()`
(all those inside the `DisconnectOperation` class).

My problem is the fact that based on my observations, calling `blutetoohGatt.disconnect()` disconnects the classic BT profile (PBAP) as well.

Is it an expected behaviour?

I have investigated the code of generic Android P framework and it looks that calling `bluetoothGatt.disconnect() -> bluetoothGatt.close()` completely disconnects the device described by the given MAC Address:
[`BluteoothGatt#disconnect()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.java#898)
[`BlutetoothGatt#close()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.java#712)
[`BlutetoothGatt#unregisterApp()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.java#824)

I would risk a statement that I have quite unusual BLE use-case scenario where the phone (Central/Client) and the peripheral (custom Android HW/Server) are connected simultaneously via Classic BT profile and via BLE.
I suspect that disconnecting/closing device using its BT MAC address disconnect both profiles, hence the contacts sharing stops working.
Is it possible to disconnect BLE connection only, but not affect the classic BT (SPP/PBAP) connections between the two devices?

Comment: More info about the case is available in [a Github issue](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/issues/720)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation described on [that Github issue](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/issues/720)
I realised that my custom hardware is equipped with dual-mode BT adapter so it supports classic BT (BR/EDR) and the BLE one.
As soon as I pair an Android phone with the custom hardware via System Settings, classic BT profiles are bonded, but also my GATT Server advertises relevant services using the same MAC address which is used by the BR/EDR. Disconnecting BLE client connection disconnect BD/EDR as well.

What helps in my case is to not start pairing via System Settings, but let the GATT server advertise and let my BLE client app to connect (and trigger pairing) first. As a result I have a BLE connection with server available under "AA:AA:AA:AA:xx", while the classic BT profiles are connected to "BB:BB:BB:BB:yy" interface on the custom hardware.
**Now, disconnecting BLE profile does not disconnect the classic one.**

I am looking for a solution which would allow my GATT Server to be advertised with BLE only, but no luck so far.
Here are some interesting links I have found:

[connectGatt creates connection over BT Classic instead of BLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127107/connectgatt-on-samsung-galaxy-s7-creates-connection-over-bluetooth-classic-inste)

[how to force BLE "just works" pairing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307555/how-to-force-bluetooth-le-just-works-pairing-in-android)

[BLE Dual-Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321892/bluetooth-le-dual-mode)